# How to create structured arrays with list and array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a list A of the form:

```
A = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']
```

and an array B of the form:

```
B = [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
     [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
     [13 14 15 16 17 18]
     [19 20 21 22 23 24]]
```

now I would like to create a structured array C of the form:

```
C = [[ P  Q  R  S  T  U]
     [ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
     [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
     [13 14 15 16 17 18]
     [19 20 21 22 23 24]]
```

so that I can extract columns with column names P, Q, R, etc. I tried the following code but it does not create a structured array and gives the following error.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
A = (['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
C = np.vstack((A, B))
print (C)
D = C['P']
```

**Error**

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How to create structured array in Python in this case?

**Update**

Both are variables, their shape changes during runtime but both list and array will have the same number of columns.

Comment: Are there some columns missing in `B`?

Comment: I have updated array B.

Comment: What do you mean with change? Increase ... decrease? At least `numpy` 'prefers' to have a fixed shape which is why you should first get all data and then you start the numpy machinery

Comment: I meant the number of columns might increase or decrease depending on the data set.

Comment: Your `C` does not look like a structured array (as produced by `genfromtxt`).  At best it is a dtype object array containing both strings and numbers, or an array of strings, with quotes edited out.

Comment: Yes, I know, that is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in pure `numpy` you can do

```
A = np.array(['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'])
B = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
              [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
              [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

# define the structured array with the names from A
C = np.zeros(B.shape[0],dtype={'names':A,'formats':['f8','f8','f8','f8','f8','f8']})

# copy the data from B into C
for i,n in enumerate(A):
    C[n] = B[:,i]

C['Q']
array([  2.,   8.,  14.,  20.])
```

Edit: you can automatize the format list by using instead

```
C = np.zeros(B.shape[0],dtype={'names':A,'formats':['f8' for x in range(A.shape[0])]})
```

Furthermore, the names do not appear in `C` as data but in `dtype`. In order to get the names from `C` you can use

```
C.dtype.names
```

Comment: Do I have to add formats for each columns, any other workaround for large number of columns?

Comment: @nxcr : I think you need the `formats` part but you can automatize it -> see my edit

Comment: The headers are missing in C. How to keep the headers (i.e. array A) in array C?

Comment: @nxcr : Because the names are not part of the data. For a list of the names type `C.dtype.names`. You can also see them in `dtype` when you just type `C`. When you want to have something like an Excel 'view' you have to use `pandas` instead

Comment: But when I generate arrays using np.genfromtxt() I get such headers.

Comment: If the first line in a structured array consists of `string` elements I would expect that all the data are also stored as `strings`. Are you sure the number below the names appear as `floats`? However, `names` in structured `numpy.arrays` do not appear in the data but in `dtype` as far as I know. If you don't like it you have to use `pandas` as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Is it possible to make C a 2D array?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library is for:

```
>>> A = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']
>>> B = np.arange(1, 25).reshape(4, 6)
>>> B
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(B, columns=A)
    P   Q   R   S   T   U
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18
3  19  20  21  22  23  24
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(B, columns=A)
>>> df['P']
0     1
1     7
2    13
3    19
Name: P, dtype: int64
>>> df['T']
0     5
1    11
2    17
3    23
Name: T, dtype: int64
>>>
```

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs on:

```
D = C['P']
```

Here is a simple approach, using regular Python lists on the title row.

```
import numpy as np
A = (['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
    [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
C = np.vstack((A, B))
print (C)
D = C[0:len(C), list(C[0]).index('P')]
print (D)
```